# Setting timestamp to nsuserdefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, timestamp, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to set timestamp to nsuserdefaults and then check, if it changed, then do action?

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"timestamp"])
 {

 }
```

Comment: Do you want to store the timestamp, or a value with the timestamp as a key. In your example you are using the timestamp as a key.

Comment: I need something with which I can do a check if changes was made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store the timestamp itself in the NSUserDefaults, but you can store an integer representing the TimeStamp, these you can easily compare.

Check this for an example;
[Example of timestamp - int conversion, storing in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655117/time-passed-between-launches-iphone)

Comment: how do I check if it changed?

Comment: What will you be checking it against? You need two values if you want to compare, can you try to give a little more info?

Comment: I have a lot of annotations and in my settings modalview I have switches, with switches I set categories of annotations to OFF/ON and when I go back to my mapview, it always reload my annotations, even if I not changed switch position.

Comment: I think you original question in no way represents the issue you are having here. I would post a new question that fully details what problem you are running into. Include code from both your settings modalview and your map and annotations so people can see what you are doing. Without that information it is very hard to help you find a solution to the real problem.